# GFCI pigtail in service panel

Tags: electrical-panel, gfci

I'm adding a GFCI circuit breaker in my main service panel. The neutral pigtail from the GFCI breaker is not long enough to reach my neutral/ground bar, unless routed in the space between the service disconnect and the circuit breakers, above the hot bars. See photo. My panel is the same model as the one shown.

I've never seen a wire routed through this space, so I'm assuming it is a no-go. Is my assumption correct? If so, what is an NEC compliant way to extend the pigtail? The pigtail wire doesn't appear to be replaceable at the breaker.

[image: wire above hot bars?]

Comment: Crouse-Hinds?  They use GE's general concept of "half width" 2-pole breakers straddling breaker spaces. Make sure there aren't any 1/2" wide openings in the panel face,  Either fill them with individual 120V 1/2 width breakers, or listed cover plates. Siemens should support this panel with *at least* cover plates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extend the pigtail with a wire nut. Wire nuts and other splices ARE allowed in panels per NEC.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the pigtail with a longer wire so you can route it the way that makes the most sense. Make sure it's the right gauge and that it's white.

Comment: Thanks for the response.